# Refresh datagridview1 on form1 each time form2 is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I refresh **datagridview1** on form1 each time form2 is closed?

i.e. `refreshDataGridView1()` needs to be run, but I'm not too sure how to go about initializing it.

What needs to go in `refreshDataGridView1()`?

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (pgpText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following textbox: PGP");
    }
    else if (teamText.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following textbox: Team");
    }
    else
    {

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            string pgp_new = pgpText.Text;
            string pgp_old = pgpOld.Text;
            string team = teamText.Text;
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='db.mdb'";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE PGP SET PGP=?,Team=? WHERE PGP=?";
            command.Parameters.Add("pgp_new", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pgp_new;
            command.Parameters.Add("team", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = team;
            command.Parameters.Add("pgp_old", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pgp_old;
            conn.Open();

            int affectedRows = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (affectedRows == 0)
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PGP (PGP,Team) VALUES (?, ?)";
                command.Parameters.RemoveAt(2);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (MessageBox.Show("Table Saved!", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //refreshDataGridView1();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }

            if (affectedRows > 0)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Table Saved!", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //refreshDataGridView1();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `OnFormClosing` event of your `Form2` and in that event call your method `refreshDataGridView1()`

**EDIT:**

In your `refreshDataGridView1()` method just rebind the grid like

```
private void refreshDataGridView1()
{
  GridView1.DataSource = <some data Source>;
}
```

Comment: Yes but what needs to go in `refreshDataGridView1()`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make a function in Form1 and call it upon exiting in Form2 (Form_Closing). I mean when Form2 is closing, call the function. The function should update your datagridview.

How can you access the function? Well, you can easily pass **this** to Form2 while creating:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
```

And in your Form2:

```
private Form1 frm1;

public Form2(Form1 frm1)
{
    this.frm1 = frm1;
}

private void Form2_Form_Closing(...)
{
    this.frm1.UpdateDataGridViewFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat your Form2 as a Dialog. Move your MessageBox and UpdateDatagridview logic in Form1. Whenever you have finished your query (in Form2), pass `DialogResult.OK`. It will also close your form.

Form2:

```
if (affectedRows > 0)
{
     //ok some rows were affected, close the form and pass OK result
     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Back in Form1:

```
private void openForm2()
{
    var f2 = new Form2(); //create new form2
    var formResult = f2.ShowDialog(); //open as Dialog and check result after close event
    if (formResult == DialogResult.OK) //check form2 dialog result
    {
        //form2 gave OK, I can update my DGV and display msg
        MessageBox.Show("DGV will be updated", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        //update my DGV
        UpdateDGV();
    }
    else
    {
        //form2 passed Cancel or something else, not good
        MessageBox.Show("Form2 Closed but nothing happened.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}   

private void UpdateDGV() {
    //refresh datagridview1 datasource
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `Form2_FormClosed` event:

```
this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosed);

private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
refreshDataGridView1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridView.DataSource = dataset; // get new result set
```

Something like this should go in refreshDataGridView1()

For accessing Form1 elements in Form2 add a public property in Form1.

```
public DataGridView DataGridView1 
{
    return dataGrid; // this should be your data grid id
}
```

In form2, you can access form1 as

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
```

If one form contains another you can create a constructor to pass one to another.

```
private Form1 form1;
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1 = form1;
}
```

Comment: OP is using `winform`. So from where does `Bind` method comes? You might want to check `DataGridView` class in MSDN.

Comment: Removed that line. Thanks :-)

Comment: How would I reference the datagridview in form1 from form 2? Because this would be running in form 2

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier Add a property in your form2 which will return the DataGridView.